# case statement in where clause for avoiding checking null evaluation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query like

```
case when (
  select sum(amount) 
  from table 
  where id in(10,100) 
    and to_char(month,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(@date::date,'YYYY-MM')
) is null 
then (
  select sum(amount) 
  from table 
  where id in(10,100) 
    and to_char(month,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(@date::date- interval '1 month','YYYY-MM')
)
else (
  select sum(amount) 
  from table 
  where id in(10,100) 
    and to_char(month,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(@date::date,'YYYY-MM')
) end
```

I just need to rewrite this query where we can use a case statement in where clause in postgres

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you clarify with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want smthing like this, but it is not very clear.

```
coalesce(select sum(amount) 
      from table 
      where id in(10,100) 
        and to_char(month,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(@date::date,'YYYY-MM')
    ,
     select sum(amount) 
      from table 
      where id in(10,100) 
        and to_char(month,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(@date::date- interval '1 month','YYYY-MM')
    )
```

Comment: i dont think the above will work.. i am checking whether there is any result for one condtion if its not there i am checking with another condition.i need to know whether we can do the same with a case statement in where clause..